Change "Hot Network Questions" to "Trending Network Questions"?
The word Hot in Hot Network Questions feels like it carries a sexual connotation.
Should the phrase Hot Network Questions be changed to Trending Network Questions?
Do you think the latter is more appropriate?

Do you feel the same way when someone says "wow, its hot out there today" - does that have a sexual connotation? No? Why does "hot network question" have a sexual connotation to you?

Somebody has to mention that this is somewhat hilarious  (btw let's migrate to elu probably )

@nicael Here’s an example question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/how-to-express-that-the-temperature-is-high/55519#55519

"hot" is very commonly used for things that are "trending". For example "hottest fashion" when talking about latest/most modern fashion. Even in the realm of online topics - Reddit has sorting by "hot". Other sites also have it but Reddit is one of the biggest. And I doubt many users think that's the sexiest topics.

In English, the phrase "hot topic" has been a known idiom since at least the 1950s. It's common in advertising to use implicit language hinting at sex, but you wish to modify that emergent (and successful) strategy - in favour of what alternative (that's equivalently successful)? What is your proposal here? "Trending" is a functional but lackluster word by advertising standards.

'Hot' only has a... that connotation when used in a... that context. No one is going to say 'Oh what a high-temperature day' just because 'Hot' can have a questionable connotation in some contexts.

Words acquire sexual connotations through people using them to talk implicitly about sex, due to social norms against explicit talk about sex. If people avoid using a word with sexual connotations in other contexts, the sexual connotations become the main meaning of the word. Thus the word now is explicitly about sex and cannot be used to implicitly talk about sex anymore. Hence the aforementioned social norms strike again and other words will acquire a sexual connotation. (Also see euphemism treadmill.)
Hence, as long as those social norms exist, there will always be “everyday” words that have sexual connotations. Trying to avoid this is futile and just furthers sex negativity, lack of sexual education, and other bad things – which also are at the root of those social norms.

Why do you think that “hot” is sexual? Can you explain a little bit more?
“hot” definitely has a sexual meaning, according to Oxford Dictionary (see here).
I definitely won’t first think that “hot” means sexual things, as “hot” has many different meanings.
Like when I say the sentence “I am hot.” below the scorching hot sun, what do you think I mean in that sentence above? Sexual meaning or what?
I don’t think that it is a good idea to change the word “Hot” to “Trending”, it is wasting the community’s time. And “Hot” and “Trending” all mean the same thing.
Extra point:
For those users that who are not good in English, they maybe know the meaning of “hot”, but don’t know the meaning of “trending”. So, my suggestion is don’t change the word.
